# Getting a 400 bad request error when using RestAssured

Tags: java, postman, rest-assured

I am getting a 400 error on a POST request in InteliJ/Java/RestAssured but not in Postman, so can anyone advise where I am getting it wrong please
First Postman

```
Endpoint: https://xxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

[image]

And my body params are

```
client_id       anvalidid
client_secret   shhhhitisasecret    
scope           https://xxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/read    
grant_type      client_credentials
```

Now when I post this I get a 200 response and a nice new access token.
When I try the same in Java/RestAssured I get a 400 bad request error, this is what I post.

```
Endpoint: https://xxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

Body

```
{
"client_id":"anvalidid",
"client_secret":"shhhhitisasecret",
"scope":"https://xxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/read",
"grant_type":"client_credentials"
}

Header: "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Every time I run this I get HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error, I cannot figure out why.
Can anyone see where I am going wrong please.
Thanks in advance.

Below are the returned headers

```
Date=Thu, 03 Jun 2021 10:45:55 GMT
Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding=chunked
Connection=keep-alive
Set-Cookie=XSRF-TOKEN=093edd16-255e-42ad-9f11-be84cd56c5dc; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
x-amz-cognito-request-id=4c91be06-9d0b-47d9-997e-f292eee61650
X-Application-Context=application:prod:8443
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma=no-cache
Expires=0
Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options=DENY
Server=Server
```

And cookies

```
XSRF-TOKEN=093edd16-255e-42ad-9f11-be84cd56c5dc;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did some hunting around and managed to sort a solution, as below

```
Response response = RestAssured
        .given()
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .formParam("client_id", "clientId")
        .formParam("client_secret", "clientSecret")
        .formParam("scope", "https://scope.etc")
        .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
        .request()
        .post(settingsRepository.getSetting("cognito.url.base"));
```

Live and learn